# Почему участок кода мешает другому участку кода работать?

Tags: python, discord

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await client.process_commands(message)

    with open ('C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\server\\lvl.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)
    async def update_data(users,user):
        if not user in users:
            users[user] = {}
            users[user]['exp'] = 0
            users[user]['lvl'] = 1
    async def add_exp(users,user,exp):
        users[user]['exp'] += exp
    async def add_lvl(users, user):
        pls = users [user]['exp']
        vls = users [user]['lvl']
        if pls > vls:
            await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention}Получает {vls} уровень')
            users[user]['exp'] = 0
            users[user]['lvl'] = vls + 1


            
             
    await update_data(users, str(message.author.id))
    await add_exp(users,str(message.author.id),0.1)
    await add_lvl(users,str(message.author.id))
#await вызывает функцию
    with open ('C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\server\\lvl.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users,f)
```

Этот участок мешает работать другому участку кода

```
cxs = ['пока', 'привет']
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    else:
        content = message.content.split()
        for word in content:
            if word in cxs:
                await message.delete()




    await client.process_comand(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

Насколько мне известно, определённое событие можно обрабатывать только в одной функции. По крайней мере, у меня была аналогичная ситуация, но когда я обе функции объединил в одну, то всё сразу стало работать.